# Customizing gutter and column sizes of Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

Our designer designed the website without using a grid system, however luckily I found a grid system to fit it with playing some settings. It's still 12 grids but gutter and column sizes are different than the bootstrap's.. and I want to ask some questions at this point.

- Is this a good behaviour to customise bootstrap from Bootstrap's official customizer or Bootstrap Live Customizer?
- What is the best approach to take while you want to customize and keep responsiveness at the same time?

The settings I want to change is gutter size and column sizes. I know how to use bootstrap but I have never tried to customize it. I thought customizing bootstrap beforehand would be a better practice than using padding/margin to almost every element, which I believe complex adapting responsiveness.

What is the proper way of calculating it? And for example on Bootstrap's official customizer, which fields should I change? How should I calculate sizes for all screen sizes?

---

He also used 1440 x 900 while designing.

What is the best way to adapt this grid settings below? Here I'm adding the grid settings that I could fit the design:

[image]

Comment: *"Is this a good behaviour to customise bootstrap from Bootstrap's official customizer"* -- sure, why not? Isn't that what it's for? *"What is the best approach to take while you want to customize and keep responsiveness at the same time?"* -- I **believe**, but don't quote me on this, that the customizer should be smart enough to keep it responsive no matter what settings you change.

Comment: Can you please help me on which settings to change to adapt my settings into bootstrap? I am very confused on how to make the calculations.

Comment: I don't think you have to make any calculations. The customizer automatically calculates everything using your values when it compiles the css. To change the gutter size, you can go here: https://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system and adjust the `@grid-gutter-width` and it will calculate everything else for you based on that value. However, columns usually use percentages for widths so I don't think you can use fixed sizes. For example, a column in a 12 column layout will get a width of `1/12` or `8.333%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a set of variables that you can override in your project if you want. [_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L197)

Max width: `$container-max-widths`,
number of columns: `$grid-columns`,
and gutter size: `$grid-gutter-width-base`.
What's more, you can set different gutter sizes for each screen size: `$grid-gutter-widths`.

You can use not precompiled css file of bootstrap, but scss version of it and compile scss files by yourself.

---

**Update:**

Ups, author uses less version of Bootstrap. So you can change less variables: `@gridColumns`, `@gridColumnWidth`, `@gridGutterWidth`, and so on.

Comment: Use !default for all variables, like this:
**$container-max-widths: 1440px !default;**
 and set variables before you require bootstrap.